# Window settings 'Last Used Tool' F6 (automatic appearance)

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, interface, edit-mode

During working, we often use the basic modeling tools (Extrude, Bevel, Loop Cut And Slide, etc.) After applying these tools can be tweaking (hotkey F6)
Is it possible make it so that this window appear automatically with these instruments?
[image]

Maybe such script already exists?

Comment: If you open the left hand helper pane thing of the 3d view (with N or T i think) the lower part of that should be the same as the F6 popup. Not makingreal answer presently because on phone and out of practice so can't confirm.

Comment: About the bottom panel I know. it is not always easily accessible


When this panel appears automatically modeling becomes a much easier and more convenient